# BigQuery scheduled query: Cannot create a transfer in > JURISDICTION_US when destination dataset is located in > REGION_ASIA_SOUTHEAST_1

Tags: google-bigquery

I am getting this error quite frequently while trying to create a scheduled query

> Error creating scheduled query: Cannot create a transfer in
>   JURISDICTION_US when destination dataset is located in
>   REGION_ASIA_SOUTHEAST_1

I just need a scheduled query to overwrite data in a table.

Comment: As far as I could investigate, this might be a transient known issue which needs to be further troubleshooted by GCP support team. Please refer to [Support contact page](https://console.cloud.google.com/support) to open a ticket. Meantime, I would suggest to use [CLI command](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/scheduling-queries#setting_up_a_scheduled_query) to set up your scheduled query.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem while trying to create a scheduled query with python:

```
400 Cannot create a transfer in REGION_EUROPE_WEST_1 when destination dataset is located in JURISDICTION_EU
```

I figured out that even my project is located in europe-west1 but my destination dataset was located in multinational location: **Europe**. I had to update my parent path : **parent=project_path** to '{project_path}/**locations/eu**' so that it works.

I hope that it helps someone.

Comment: When using `bigquery_datatransfer.CreateTransferConfigRequest`, seems if you don't specify a `datasetId`  the location has to be in the `parent`.

Comment: This solved my issue. I had this problem with the Cloud Console UI and found that if I added `&parent={ project }/locations/eu` in the URL, pressed enter/return, then created the scheduled query again after the window loaded. Seems that it worked! Could have been a weird coincidence, though?

Answer (score 3):

It's look like as a bug from BQ.
I got the same problems, with source and destination dataset located in EU both.
I've change just for testing purpose the destination for an other EU dataset, and it works.
I've finally update the scheduled query to use my first destination choice and now it works.. I can't explain why, but it's seem to be a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, you can try with starting from the Scheduled Queries BigQuery UI and click on "+ create schedule query" button, then I don't get error. If I start directly in BigQuery UI I get the same error.

Answer (score 1):

I had this error and tried many of the solutions in this thread. I tried a new session in an incognito window and it worked so I believe this is a transient issue as suggested.

Comment: I had exactly the same experience. All datasets in EU but the scheduled query UI just refused to create it. Using a private window and re-logging in and it worked just fine. No idea why this solution got a downvote.

Comment: Same here! I made it work once, and the second time it was not working. So I so this comment and try in incognito, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

As I tried, it may happen because I have existed table with the same id as the destination table. This happens even if the table is the result of manually running that query and saved.

Comment: Have you found the solution? I started getting this error today. Last week I was able to schedule almost the same query I try today.

Comment: Yup. Just delete the dest table first.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue recently.I tried 2 things and they worked:

1. try setting the query location to destination dataset/table location, then try scheduling the query.
2. If that does not work try to run the query and save results to the intended table in bigquery i.e. try creating the destination table with storing the results of the query you are trying to schedule first. Then try scheduling the query.

Both cases worked for me in different cases.

Answer (score 0):

I just scheduled query `select 1` and then edited it to the needed one – it worked

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/27330626)

Comment: @rinkesh This does provide an answer, though (i.e schedule a fake query before editing it to bypass the jurisdiction error).

Answer (score 0):

I think trouble with time when start schedule. If it is in the past relative to local time, then bg tries to run the request on another server.

Comment: I had high hopes, but this was not the issue for me. Still looking for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. The way I solved it was to disable the editor tabs (there is a button at the top). Then opened the query settings and set the processing location to EU manually.

Answer (score 0):

I was using `bq` command when I came across this issue and was able to resolve it by adding parameter `--location='europe-west1`

So my final query looked like this

```
bq query \
--use_legacy_sql=false \
--display_name='my_table' \
--location='europe-west1' \
'''create or replace table my_dataset.my_table as (select * from external_query('projects/my_mysql_connection/locations/europe-west1/connections/bi', '(select * from my_table)'))'''
```