# BigQuery scheduled query: Cannot create a transfer in JURISDICTION_US when destination dataset is located in REGION_EUROPE_NORTH_1

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

Got this error when setting up new scheduled query.

> BigQuery scheduled query: Cannot create a transfer in >
> JURISDICTION_US when destination dataset is located in >
> REGION_EUROPE_NORTH_1

I try schedule query from Query editor > Schedule query.
Location in query setting and destination table location are both "europe-north-1".

Answer (score 0):

Scheduled query not supports cross-region query.

[image]

Is table JURISDICTION_US's region is europe_north_1 too?

The table seems to be in US just by name..

You should check both table's region(queried table and destination table) before run scheduled query.

Refer [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/scheduling-queries#supported_regions) to get information about scheduled query support region.

If both table's regions are different, you need to migrate one to the other.

Refer [how to moving bigquery data between locations](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/locations#moving-data) to get guide for migration.

Comment: I querying a table called orders_table. This table is in dataset with location 'europe-north-1'. Query just get some data from orders_table, aggregate it, and writes result to the orders_agg table, that is in same dataset, as an orders table.

Comment: I found same question in stackoverflow. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60259740/bigquery-scheduled-query-cannot-create-a-transfer-in-jurisdiction-us-when-des

Comment: Ugh, I have the same problem. All my datasets are in the EU so I don't know why I'm getting this JURISDICTION_US error.